# lirc_serial module missing 18.04+

Tags: drivers, kernel, serial-port, lirc

On Unbuntu 20.04, I want to configure lirc for IR blasting over serial port.  But it seems that the latest linux kernel is missing the necessary "lirc_serial.ko" module (missing since Linux 4.15, at least).

I've found a number of instructions on configuring lirc with serial port, but they all seem very outdated and depends on "lirc_serial.ko" to be present.

How do I add the necessary "lirc_serial.ko" module to my system?   I have found a "serial_ir.ko" module, but I don't think it is the same.    Do I have to build lirc myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Arch Linux folks, I [found](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LIRC#Receiver_and_transmitter_configuration) that in the latest kernels (since 4.9), `lirc_serial` has been dropped in favor of `serial_ir`

I had to add the following file `/etc/modprobe.conf/serial-ir.conf` to configures `serial_ir` to use the desired port with the following content:

```
options serial_ir irq=4 io=0x3f8     #COM1 equivalent, /dev/ttyS0

install serial_ir /usr/bin/setserial /dev/ttyS0 uart none;/usr/sbin/modprobe --ignore-install serial_ir
```

1. `options` line defines which port to use (e.g. COM1, /dev/ttyS0)
2. `install` line instructs the kernel drop control of relevant port

The `serial_ir` module can be loaded simply creating `/etc/module-load.d/serial_ir.conf` with the following content:

```
serial_ir
```

**OR**

in `lirc` v10+, by adding the following to the `lirc_options.conf` file:

```
[modinit]
code = /usr/sbin/modprobe serial_ir
```

or in `lirc` v9, by extending the `TRANSMITTER_MODULE` variale in `hardware.conf` file as such:

```
TRANSMITTER_MODULES="...serial_ir"
```

where `...` are the other modules already specified in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the functionality of lirc has been moved into the kernel on recent Ubuntu releases.

So, you need to uninstall lirc and make sure that `ir-keytable` is installed instead. Then, in `terminal` type `man ir-keytable` to get started.

Plug in your remote dongle, and in `terminal`, type `ir-keytable` and this will give you the basic information you'll need to get started. Then use `ir-keytable -t` to get/review your scan codes. You'll save a keymap in `/etc/rc_keymaps` (you can get a prebuilt keymap file from `/lib/udev/rc_keymaps/`), and edit `/etc/rc_maps.cfg` if you need to.

If you Google `ir-keytable` you'll get plenty of how-to articles to help you. See http://madaboutbrighton.net/articles/2015/remote-control-media-player-without-lirc-using-ir-keymap

Comment: Thanks for reply, but your response seems to be about receive IR signals (into PC).  I'm looking for a solution to **transmit** IR signal using the UART serial port, something that was supported by default in linux driver until recently.

Comment: @codechimp The answer was mostly to inform you about lirc being missing since 18.04+, and although it may be primarily about receiving, it may give you enough clues to research the transmit side. Also note that lirc is still in the repos.